How can I delete a feature branch once it's been merged with Sourcetree?
I am using Sourcetree for my Git repo, which exists in Gitlab. I am creating merge requests on Gitlab's website when I want to merge to development. Once it is merged to dev, I want to delete the feature branch, but I get a message in Sourcetree saying that it hasn't been merged yet. I need to select the force delete option every time to actually delete it.
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks branch -d <feature branch>
error: the branch <feature branch> is not fully merged
hint: If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D <feature branch>'
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.forceDeleteBranch false"

Is there a way I can have Sourcetree recognize that it was merged to dev through Gitlab?

When you complete the Merge Request, which merge method are you using? (The behavior you're witnessing could be explained by using rebase or squash.)
